# I am trying to translate this function into assembly, but I dont understand what it is doing

Tags: c, assembly

For an assignment I have to transfer this C function into assembly language:

```
void asma(unsigned long x[], unsigned long y[], unsigned long r[])
{
    unsigned long borrow, r0;
    r0 = x[0] - y[0];
    borrow = r0 > x[0];
    r[0] = r0;
    r[1] = x[1] - y[1] - borrow;

}
```

I have trouble understanding what this function actually is doing, especially the last line confuses me. I also don`t understand what the borrow bit is doing in this context.

I was hoping someone could explain this function to me, and perhaps use a example with real numbers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to know what your function does in order to translate into assembly language. Compiler usually know nothing, or very little about what a function does and they are able to do the translation.

Comment: Looks like you just need to know that, in C, when you evaluate a boolean such as `r0 > x[0]`, the result is `1` if true, and `0` if false. Does that help? But as another hint: I would use the carry bit in the CPU instead. The C function uses a separate `borrow` argument because it doesn't give the programmer direct access to the carry bit.

Comment: When the C compiler generates a boolean result and this is "true", does it always map "true" to the value "1"? It could be any non-zero value.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: Yes, relational expressions always evaluate to 0 or 1 (in the abstract machine, what the compiler does under the hood is another thing). (FWIW, same goes for `!`, equality, `&&`, and `||`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, `borrow` is not a bit, but a full `unsigned long` variable (probably 32 bits).

What this code seems to do is a substraction of a large number whose digits are held in the elements of `x` and `y`. The function does that by substracting first the two elements that contain the least significant digit. If there is a borrow, they store it to use it later in the next element.

This function is not complete though. The original one should have a loop iterating from the first element to the last.

To do this in assembler, take into account that you won't probably need the borrow variable. If your machine has a `SUB` instructioni and `SBB` instruction (`SUB` with borrow) you can just `SUB` the first two elementos (`x[0]` and `y[0]`) and then `SBB` the rest of them. `SBB` takes into account the borrow of the last operation. Just don't issue any operation that might alter the borrow/carry flag between `SBB`'s (or save the flags register into memory or another register)

Answer (score 2):

Jakob

Without knowing your level of knowledge in C or assembler, this is fundamental.

Decompose the function:

The three arguments to the function (`x[], y[] and r[]`) are pointers to array (addressable) memory and will be pushed onto the stack frame and available to the function body.

The two 'local' values (`borrow, r0`) will be used to accumulate information and are typically when registers are used to manage them.

The first instruction `r0 = x[0] - y[0];` is saying ***take the value at offset 0 for x and subtract the value at offset 0 for y from that, and store the result in register r0***.

The next instruction `borrow = r0 > x[0];` is saying ***take the value of register r0 and do a greater-than compare to the value at offset 0 for x. Store the result of that in the borrow register***.

`r[0] = r0;` is saying ***take the value of register r0 and store it back to offset 0 for r***. This effectively destroys the value that previously may have occupied the first position of the r array.

The final instruction `r[1] = x[1] - y[1] - borrow;` ***is saying from offset 1 of x, subtract the value of offset 1 of y and then, from that, subtract the value of register borrow, storing the result to offset 1 of r.*** In assembler I'd probably put x[1] in a register, subtract the value of y[1] from it and then subtract the borrow register from that before storing it back to r[1].

Comment: See if the answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354941/retrieving-data-in-x86-64) helps your understanding.